# jQuery remove appears to be acting asynchronously

Tags: jquery, asynchronous

I believe the remove function is really synchronous though, which is why this is so confusing.

I have a list of divs with a `span3` class. The divs can be removed. The first occurrence of a div with `span3` must always have the `first` class

If the div that currently has the `first` class is removed, by calling:

```
$('#'+id).remove();
```

and the first is reassigned by calling:

```
$('.span3').first().addClass('first');
```

Why does the first occurence of .span3 only sometimes get assigned the `first` class?

The full snippet:

```
$.get('someFile.php', function(data) {              
    $('#'+id).remove();
    $('.span3').first().addClass('first');
});
```

Comment: If it's easy to reproduce - check what `$('.span3')` returns in debugger

Comment: Yep, it correctly selects the right element when I run it in console, every time I've tried anyway.

Comment: Double check then that `$('#'+id)` and `$('.span3').first()` select desired elements

Comment: Yes they do, but the element that is selected also has the span3 class, and is the first span3 class. When I execute in console it works, but when I execute in that callback it doesn't always work.

Comment: The simple workaround could be to use `'.span3:not(#'+id+')'` selector, since I'm not sure how what you're explaining is possible. What browser do you use?

Comment: I'm in Chrome. The workaround didn't work either, here is my console output:

http://pastebin.com/FK75iGse

As you can see, the identical code works in the console, but not after the callback. The callback successfully remove the element but did not assign the `first` class to the new first `span3`.

I'm really confused, I'm probably missing something very obvious.

Comment: `68` **is not** a valid `id` attribute value http://stackoverflow.com/a/79022/251311

Comment: Oh wow! Very interesting, thanks! Will try with that fixed and report back.

Comment: That was it, fascinating! Thanks for that, wouldn't have found that for a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`68` isn't a valid `id` attribute value.

More details at https://stackoverflow.com/a/79022/251311